# ASP.Net secure Ajax authentication

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, authentication

I want to make my `ASP.Net` site authentication seamless using `Ajax` call.
So I consider using [client side authentication service of microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398896.aspx) that should be used via `HTTPS` because it sends username and password in `plain-text` format.
And the problem is that I can't use `SSL` in my site.

So I found a way to hash data before passing to web service that is described [here](http://evolt.org/node/60505)
but the problem is there is a salt in `DB` that should passed to client for creating hashed password (that equals to `DB` saved password). and this is not safe.

Is there a better way for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.

Check this out: [Secure AJAX Authentication without SSL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/SecureAjaxAuthentication.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.
We will use RSA for encrypting username ans password.
in summery I'll have a web service that creates RSA keypair and save it (this key will be regenerated every day to be more secure).

I will have a textbox or hidden field that calls this service and get the public key.
the for encrypt username and password with [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/) library client side and pass this to my authentication service using ajax call.

so the server will decrypt them with private key and the authenticate user.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you were looking for an ASP.NET version of jCryption for bi-directional communication, which you mentioned you tried, you can find one on GitHub here: [jCryptionNET](https://github.com/triniMahn/jCryptionNET)